# Waiting for a specific event in Powershell

Tags: security, events, powershell

I am  writing a script in powershell, that will wait for a specific event in Windows 7.
Event ID 4776, in the Security Log. The script will run when the computer is locked.

The script is supposed to run in idle, essentially a while(true) loop, and it will wait for the "Failed Audit" of the event to occur. Once the event happens, it will add one to a counter. Once the event happens in a "Success Audit" status, it will break from the loop and thus be done with the script.

My initial idea, was to take the date of the event and compare to the date of running time and if it matches, then etc.

What I have so far:

```
$i=0
while(true){       
   $date = Get-Date -format G
   $eventtime_fail=Get-EventLog Security | ? {$_.EventId -eq 4776} | where {$_.entrytype -eq "FailureAudit"} | Select-Object -expand TimeGenerated | Select -first 1
   $eventtime_success=Get-EventLog Security | ? {$_.EventId -eq 4776} | where {$_.entrytype -eq "SuccessAudit"} | Select-Object -expand TimeGenerated | Select -first 1

    if($date -eq $eventtime_fail){
         $i++
     }
    else if($date -eq $eventtime_success){
          break
     }
}
```

I realize that i could just simply create a scheduled task and be done with it but I really need this to be standalone. This script will run once the computer locks, and stops execution once the computer is unlocked.

In Windows XP, there was a way for a script to wait for an event to occur and then run some sort of instruction, which is what I need, this was called eventtriggers.exe, it was removed when vista came out and scheduled tasks replaced it, however, scheduled tasks does not work the same way via powershell script.

Is there anyway to do this other than the way i am doing it? Is there a way to bring eventtriggers.exe back or at least something like it? Help me people of StackOverflow, your my only hope.

Comment: Your script could schedule itself (or schedule another script) to run when the computer locks.  Would that count as "standalone"?  At least that doesn't involve you having to go configure a scheduled task. The way you're doing it now, in a `while(true)` loop, means a lot of wasted cycles.

Comment: Thats true. But My main concern so far in this script the event itself. How do I check for the event in real time. If I lock the computer, then lets say enter a bad password, the script should respond to that. But my concern is how. Which is why I was trying to do it using the time vs the time of the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test it but imo should work. Try to create an eventlog listener.

```
$seclog = Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.Log -eq 'Security'}
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $seclog -SourceIdentifier NewEventLogEntry -EventName EntryWritten -Action {

    $entry = $event.SourceEventArgs.Entry

    if($entry.EventID -eq 4776)
    {
        if($entry.EntryType -eq 'SuccessAudit')
        {
            'code for SuccessAudit'
        }
        elseif($entry.EntryType -eq 'FailureAudit')
        {
            'code for FailureAudit'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So this works. Now like any script/project, I created one more error. Sorry but this is my first time using Powershell, so prepare for  my noob comments. I edited the script to include what you added:       `while($true){                                            [your code here] 
}`  I set the loop to break once a "Success Audit" has been detected. However, because the "Register-ObjectEvent" is in the loop, powershell gives me an error saying the object has already been created.When i include the loop, it runs fine, except for the error at the end. When i exclude it, nothing.

Comment: Why adding a while loop when the listener invokes when new event is written?

Comment: Well I need this script to grab mutilple instances of the 'FailureAudits'. If I remove the while loop, nothing happens when the script runs. However, when I run the script in an infinite while loop(that breaks out when a 'SuccessAudit' occurs), the script runs fine. Upon, the "SuccessAudit', a powershell prompt is running with the following message in red: **Register-ObjectEvent: Cannot subscribe to event, a subscriber with source identifier 'NewEventLogEnter' already exists.**

Comment: You cannot register using the same identifier, change  NewEventLogEnter to something else.

Comment: Tried that but nothing works. The reason this needs to be in a loop is due to the `$seclog` variable, so i tried is something like this:

 `while($true){
 $seclog = Get-EventLog -List | Where-Object {$_.Log -eq 'Security'} ;
 Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $seclog -SourceIdentifier NewEventLogEnter$i -EventName EntryWritten -Action {
  $entry = $event.SourceEventArgs.Entry
  if($entry.EventID -eq 4776){
   if($entry.EntryType -eq 'FailureAudit'){
    $i++;
   }
   elseif($entry.EntryType -eq 'SuccessAudit'){
    [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("$i") ; 
break;
   }
  }
 }
}`

Comment: And Im still getting the error, but everything works as it supposed to. I apologize for my horrendous editing, still learning about this website. And thank you  for your help thus far

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the `SytemEvents` discribed in [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx).

You will find in [Running a script before locking or after unlocking a computer (Windows 7/Vista/XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5886056/608772) a way to start and to stop your script.