# How to subscribe to an event through Get-WinEvent in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, wait, subscription

I'm trying to listen for a specific log entry in the windows event log, that signifies that the computer has connected to the internet:

```
LogName: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational
Event ID: 10000
```

I found some code from an existing SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15959904/waiting-for-a-specific-event-in-powershell) and tried to adapt it for my purpose. The problem is that I can seemingly only find my event using [`Get-WinEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/Get-WinEvent?view=powershell-7) instead of the suggested (deprecated) [`Get-EventLog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1).

The [`EntryWritten`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) event does not seem to exist for `WinEvent` entries, is there some other event I can 'subscribe' to to listen for new entries for my event? Or should I try some other method?

```
$networklog = Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational'

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $networklog -SourceIdentifier NewEventLogEntry -EventName EntryWritten -Action {

    $entry = $event.SourceEventArgs.Entry

    if($entry.EventID -eq 10000) {
        # check_url($url)
        Write-Host "Connected"
    }
    else { 
        Write-Host "Something else"
    }
}
```

My end goal is to have a simple script running continuously that calls a function as soon as a connection to a specific url is available. Any other suggestions for achieving this would be greatly appreciated as I feel I'm in rather deep water having not touched powershell previously.

Comment: my understanding is that scheduled tasks can use an event log entry to trigger the task. have you looked into that?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I can't seem to find `Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational` with `Get-EventLog -LogName`, it says the event log does not exist.

Comment: does such an event log exist yet on the target system? does the account in use have the required privs to see it?

Comment: I provided an answer to ger you going. As for this [I feel I'm in rather deep water having not touched powershell previously.]. You really should spend the needed time for some ramp up as to avoid, confusion, misconceptions, errors, and damage to your enterprise or systems, which in turn could lead to RPE's. [resume producing events]. There are tons of free PowerShell training on Youtube and loads of other [free learning resources](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7oir35/help_with_teaching_others_powershell).

Comment: you can likely find that log thus >>> `Get-WinEvent -ListLog *network*` <<< it shows up on my old win7ps5.1 box.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I can find the event log using `Get-WinEvent`, but not using `Get-EventLog`, which would allow me to use the `EventWritten` event to listen for new matching events being written.

Comment: @BenWo - ah! i misunderstood your point. i still think that you would be better served by using the ability of Task Scheduler to use an event as a trigger.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes I agree that that would be easier, but I need the script to be deployed to numerous machines along with other scripts. I've compromised now and I'm using polling to check if the URL is reachable but I'd still prefer to use events (:

Comment: @BenWo - thank you for the added info. [*grin*] i will go back to lurking since i have no other ideas ... good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the cmdlet mentioned, you could get info by doing the following.

Tested on

```
(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).Version
# Results
<#
10.0.19041
#>
```

This works in getting the info

```
(Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational').Count
# Results
<#
2054
#>


Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational' | 
Select-Object -First 3 | 
Format-Table -AutoSize
# Results
<#
   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile

TimeCreated           Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------           -- ---------------- -------
09-Jul-20 08:54:25  4004 Information      Network State Change Fired...
09-Jul-20 08:54:22  4004 Information      Network State Change Fired...
09-Jul-20 08:54:18 20002 Information      NSI Set Category Result...
#>
```

You can only get the properties present then you have to ask for text in the property

```
(Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational' | 
Select-Object -First 1) |
Sort-Object -Property Name |
Get-Member
# Results
<#
   TypeName: System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogRecord

Name                 MemberType   Definition                                                                                                                       
----                 ----------   ----------                                                                                                                       
...                                                                                                                
Message              NoteProperty string Message=Network State Change Fired...                                                                                     
...                                                                                                      
Id                   Property     int Id {get;}                                                                                                                    
Keywords             Property     System.Nullable[long] Keywords {get;}                                                                                            
KeywordsDisplayNames Property     System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[string] KeywordsDisplayNames {get;}                                                       
Level                Property     System.Nullable[byte] Level {get;}                                                                                               
LevelDisplayName     Property     string LevelDisplayName {get;}                                                                                                   
LogName              Property     string LogName {get;}                                                                                                            
MachineName          Property     string MachineName {get;}                                                                                                        
...                                                                                               
ProcessId            Property     System.Nullable[int] ProcessId {get;}                                                                                            
Properties           Property     System.Collections.Generic.IList[System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty] Properties {get;}                             
...                                                                                         
ProviderName         Property     string ProviderName {get;}                                                                                                       
...                                                                                          
RecordId             Property     System.Nullable[long] RecordId {get;}                                                                                            
RelatedActivityId    Property     System.Nullable[guid] RelatedActivityId {get;}                                                                                   
Task                 Property     System.Nullable[int] Task {get;}                                                                                                 
TaskDisplayName      Property     string TaskDisplayName {get;}                                                                                                    
ThreadId             Property     System.Nullable[int] ThreadId {get;}                                                                                             
TimeCreated          Property     System.Nullable[datetime] TimeCreated {get;}                                                                                     
...
#>
```

Event logs store details in the Message property and you can select from there.

```
(Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational').Message | 
Select-Object -First 1
# Results
<#
Network State Change Fired
    New Internet Connection Profile: false
    Connection Cost Changed: false
    Domain Connectivity Level Changed: false
    Network Connectivity Level Changed: false
    Host Name Changed: true
    Wwan Registration State Changed: false
    Tethering Operational State Changed: false
    Tethering Client Count Changed: false
#>
```

You can use a hash table to filter for your ID

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ 
    LogName   = 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational'
    ID        = 10000 
}

# Results
<#
TimeCreated                      Id LevelDisplayName Message                                                                                                       
-----------                      -- ---------------- -------                                                                                                       
09-Jul-20 08:54:18            10000 Information      Network Connected...                                                                                          
09-Jul-20 08:54:14            10000 Information      Network Connected...                                                                                          
09-Jul-20 08:54:08            10000 Information      Network Connected... 
...
#>
```

Then it's a matter of parsing that Message into the format you choose.
Or just ask for the whole message as is

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ 
    LogName   = 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational'
    ID        = 10000 
}).Message
```

Or

```
(Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{ 
    LogName   = 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational'
    ID        = 10000 
}) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Message
```

See also:

- [PowerShell Get-WinEvent XML Madness: Getting details from event
  logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ashleymcglone/powershell-get-winevent-xml-madness-getting-details-from-event-logs)
- [Script Get-WinEventData - Extract custom EventData from the Event
  Log](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-WinEventData-Extract-344ad840)

***Update***

As LeeDaily points out, you might just be better served just setting this in TaskScheduler. If you did a direct filter config in EventViewer, you get stuff like this.

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational">*[System[(Level=1  or Level=2 or Level=3 or Level=4 or Level=0 or Level=5) and (EventID=10000)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

So, you can see the limitation of what you can natively return, and then specifically saying, if you want more, you have to dig at the Message Property value. Take a deeper look at the XML info in the link provided where when you do you end up with code like the below, with all possible output.

```
# Collect the filtered events          
$Events = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{
    LogName   = 'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational'
    ID        = 10000 
} -MaxEvents 1            
            
# Parse out the event message data            
ForEach ($Event in $Events) 
{            
    # Convert the event to XML            
    $eventXML = [xml]$Event.ToXml()  
              
    # Iterate through each one of the XML message properties            
    For ($i=0; $i -lt $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data.Count; $i++) 
    {            
        # Append these as object properties            
        $AddMemberSplat = @{
            InputObject = $Event 
            MemberType  = 'NoteProperty'
            Force       = $true
            Name        = $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].Name 
            Value       = $eventXML.Event.EventData.Data[$i].'#text'
        }
        Add-Member @AddMemberSplat           
    }            
}            
            
# View the results   
$Events | Select-Object * | Format-List
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's given me some clarity on the structure of event logs. Can I somehow subscribe to the event of "A new event matching your query has entered the event log", or should I opt for polling to check for new matching events?

Comment: I tried a different approach using `Register-WMIEvent`:
```$q = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WHERE TargetInstance ISA ` 'Win32_NTLogEvent' AND TargetInstance.EventCode = '10000' AND TargetInstance.SourceName ='NetworkProfile'"


 Register-WmiEvent -Query $q -SourceIdentifier = 'OnlineStatus' -Action $a| Out-Null``` However the query doesn't work, if I remove the filter for EventID and Source I get some events, but I can't find the specific events I'm looking for.

Comment: As for this... ["A new event matching ...]. As shown, there is no such property that contains that string. You specifically want to use the EventID/Id. If you look at the EventViewer, and use the filter feature, you see that it only is for ID's and defined keywords, not strings. You get strings by parsing the string value in the properties. To work sith subscriptions from the EventViewer, the Windows Event Collector Service must be running. Yet, I still don't understand your use case as NetworkProfile only shows as a connected state not if a URL is hit, it not a web filter which does.

Comment: I was planning on doing a check for URL connection every time a new network was connected to, to reduce the amount of pings, but I've settled on simply polling the URL every x minutes. The performance hit is insignificant in the scheme of things.