# Run powershell when windows is locked?

Tags: powershell-2.0

Is it possible to run power shell while windows is locked?

```
while (Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq 'LogonUI' }) {
    Write-Host "Windows locked out"
}
```

Comment: Hi, what do you want to do in this case ?

Comment: When Windows is in locked status, I want it to log someone off a web site.  I'm working on the first part (locked status).  I'm testing it with write-host, so when I lock my computer, I should be seeing "Windows locked out", but I'm not.

Comment: I guess you don't see the PowerShell window _because_ the computer is locked. Have you tried to, for example, write a file to disk ?

Comment: I didnt' write a file to a disk to test, but I have a write-host "Windows locked out".  It wasn't running when WIndows was locked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a script before locking a computer on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881887/running-a-script-before-locking-a-computer-on-windows)