# How can I force run script before a user lock screen?

Tags: batch-file, taskscheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I ve created task on windows 7 and I tried it also on windows server 2012 R2. neither of them work.

I want to create task to run script when a user lock off( Windows + L )

The script is running fine, but what I want is it runs after lock operation.I want to run it before lock screen is active.

I want to ask question in dialog to enter text before lock.

But when user lock off program is not shown. But when I log in again I see my program is running. But I want to ask my dialog first and then lock.

[image]
[image]
[image]
thanks in advance

Comment: Try this [Running a script before locking a computer on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881887/running-a-script-before-locking-a-computer-on-windows)

Comment: I cant understand that answer ? it can be with windows batch ?

Comment: check [runonce.exe](https://support.microsoft.com/bg-bg/kb/310593)

Comment: what is runonce.exe @npocmaka